# is the most restrictive policy in crossdomain.xml equivalent to not having at all?

Tags: flash, adobe, crossdomain.xml, html5boilerplate

I can see on the logs of my server a few http 404 
for [mydomain]/crossdomain.xml

I was wondering if to add therefore this file and configure it to have the most restrictive policy. That is: (taken from html 5 boilerplate)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
-<cross-domain-policy> 
<!-- Read this: www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html -->

<!-- Most restrictive policy: -->
 <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="none"/> 
<!-- Least restrictive policy: -->

<!-- <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/> <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false"/> <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/> -->

<!-- If you host a crossdomain.xml file with allow-access-from domain="*" and don’t understand all of the points described here, you probably have a nasty security vulnerability. ~ simon willison -->
 </cross-domain-policy>
```

**Would it be equivalent to not having at all ?**

I find the http 404 errors related to crossdomain misleading and hence I want to get rid of them so I can identify the real ones more effectively.

Comment: I may not understand the syntax well enough, but I believe that your proposed file above has a spurious '-' on line 4 column 1 (just before the opening <cross-domain-policy> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. The spec states:

> In other words, the root cross-domain policy does not contain 
>   allow-access-from directives or the HTTP headers. A meta-policy of
>   “none”  prevents the use of any other policies that may be present
>   even if the developer  included them.  It is invalid to have
>   allow-access-from or a header policy within  a root cross-domain
>   policy file with a meta-policy of “none”.  In cases where an invalid 
>   policy has both a “none” setting and other directives, “none” takes
>   precedence and no  permissions are allowed on the site.

So, I think the most restrictive technique is to use "none".